# oracle instantclient 12c EZCONNECT in Powershell Prompt for password

Tags: oracle, powershell, instantclient

I have installed instantclient 12c x86 on Windows 8.1

I am able to connect from *cmd.exe*:

```
C:\Users\vagrant>sqlplus user@\"hostname:1521/SERVICE_NAME\"

SQL*Plus: Release 12.1.0.2.0 Production on Thu Dec 3 06:22:31 2015

Copyright (c) 1982, 2014, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Enter password:

Connected to:
Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.4.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, Real Application Clusters, Automatic Storage Management,
OLAP,
Data Mining and Real Application Testing options

SQL>
```

Now when I try the same from Powershell:

I want to be prompted for password. It does not work.

```
PS C:\Users\vagrant> sqlplus user@\"hostname:1521/SERVICE_NAME\"

SQL*Plus: Release 12.1.0.2.0 Production on Thu Dec 3 06:30:12 2015

Copyright (c) 1982, 2014, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

ERROR:
ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified


Enter user-name:
```

Here I provide my password and it works

```
PS C:\Users\vagrant>sqlplus user/password@hostname:1521/SERVICE_NAME

SQL*Plus: Release 12.1.0.2.0 Production on Thu Dec 3 06:24:48 2015

Copyright (c) 1982, 2014, Oracle.  All rights reserved.


Connected to:
Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.4.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, Real Application Clusters, Automatic Storage Management, OLAP,
Data Mining and Real Application Testing options

SQL>
```

What is the correct syntax for being prompted for password logging in with sqlplus from Powershell?

Comment: `sqlplus user@hostname:1521/SERVICE_NAME`?

Comment: @PetSerAl ORA-12504: TNS:listener was not given the SERVICE_NAME in CONNECT_DATA

Comment: How about this then: `sqlplus --% user@\"hostname:1521/SERVICE_NAME\"`?

Comment: Why are you adding `\"`?

Comment: @PetSerAl the notation: sqlplus --% user@\"hostname:1521/SERVICE_NAME\" does work. Thank you! Can you explain the --% ??

Comment: @Bill_Steward The forward slash "/" indicates a password is coming up next. We need to avoid parsing of SERVICE_NAME seen as a password.